# Error compiling SSL module for Python3.9 on Debian8 64b

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, openssl, debian-jessie

I need to build **python3.9** on a **GNU/Linux Debian8 64b** system

I got the source code for the `3.9.7` version and compiled it, but I got the following error regarding the ssl module:

```
Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
```

fair enough: I downloaded the openssl code from github, checkout the tag `OpenSSL_1_1_1l` and installed it in a local path;

- re-configured the python 3.9 source tree

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/opt/python3.9 --enable-shared --with-openssl=/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1
```

- checked the `config.log` file to verify it really found the new openssl installation

```
configure:17478: checking for openssl/ssl.h in /root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1
configure:17485: result: yes
configure:17501: checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works
Trying link with OPENSSL_LDFLAGS=-L/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1/lib; OPENSSL_LIBS=-lssl -lcrypto; OPENSSL_INCLUDES=-I/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1/include
configure:17523: gcc -pthread -o conftest  -I/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1/include   -L/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1/lib conftest.c -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm >&5
configure:17523: $? = 0
configure:17525: result: yes
configure:17548: checking for X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host in libssl
configure:17577: gcc -pthread -o conftest  -I/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1/include   -L/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1/lib conftest.c -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm >&5
configure:17577: $? = 0
configure:17588: result: yes
```

so, as far as I understand, I should be able to correctly link **openssl 1.1.1** to my python 3.9 build, still, I'm getting the same error regarding the openssl version

Any suggestion of what I'm doing wrong and/or what I can do to complete the compilation process?

### Update #1

- tried to run the following command, trying to outsmart the Makefiles ;)

```
OPENSSL_LDFLAGS='-L/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1/lib' OPENSSL_LIBS=-lssl OPENSSL_INCLUDES=-I/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1/include make -j 3
```

still no success

### Update #2

inspected the compile log in detail and actually the build itself is not really failing; also the include and lib paths for openssl-1.1.1 are correct:

```
building '_ssl' extension
gcc -pthread -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fvisibility=hidden -fprofile-generate -I./Include/internal -I/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1/include -I./Include -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/root/develop/iQAC/build-folder/Python-3.9.7/Include -I/root/develop/iQAC/build-folder/Python-3.9.7 -c /root/develop/iQAC/build-folder/Python-3.9.7/Modules/_ssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/root/develop/iQAC/build-folder/Python-3.9.7/Modules/_ssl.o
gcc -pthread -shared -fprofile-generate build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/root/develop/iQAC/build-folder/Python-3.9.7/Modules/_ssl.o -L/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1/lib -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/_ssl.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more trial and errors I succeed in building all python 3.9 modules

Actually what I did was just changing the `configure` options from:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/opt/python3.9 --enable-shared --with-openssl=/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1
```

to

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/opt/python3.9 --with-openssl=/root/develop/iQAC/openssl-1.1.1 --with-computed-gotos --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-shared
```

At this point is sounds to me like an issue in the confiugration/build system, but I'm not sure about that. Comments are welcome